# Hibernate batch with stored procedure

Tags: sql, hibernate, stored-procedures

I have a Stored Procedure designed to insert a single row. I operate on it with Hibernate in the following way (simplified example):

```
public void store(int param1, int param2) {
   Connection con = session.connection();  // obtain JDBC connection from Session object
   CallableStatement stmt = con.prepareCall("{ call changesalary(?,?) }");
   stmt.setInt(1, param1);  // first parameter index start with 1
   stmt.setInt(2, param2); // second parameter
   stmt.execute();  // call stored procedure
   cleanup(con, stmt);
}
```

I wonder if it is possible to reuse this Store Procedure in a more Batch-alike way without having to modify it (I don't have the possibility of adding a new Stored Procedure or modify the existing). I want to do this:

```
public void batchStore(int[] params1, int[] params2) {
    for (int i = 0; i < params1.length; i++) {
        store(params1[i], params2[i]);
    }
}

public void store(int param1, int param2) {
   Connection con = session.connection();
   CallableStatement stmt = con.prepareCall("{ call changesalary(?,?) }");
   stmt.setInt(1, param1);
   stmt.setInt(2, param2);
   stmt.execute();
   cleanup(con, stmt);
}
```

But in order to avoid a large amount of calls to the DB, I would rather like to prepare a set of Statements, that I then batch to the database in one call:

```
public void store(int[] params1, int[] params2) {
   Connection con = session.connection();
   CallableStatement[] stmts = new CallableStatements[params.size];

   for (int i = 0; i < params1.length; i++) {
       CallableStatement stmt = con.prepareCall("{ call changesalary(?,?) }");
       stmt.setInt(1, params1[i]);
       stmt.setInt(2, params2[i]);  
       stmts[i] = stmt;
    }

    con.executeStatements(stmts);
}
```

Can the above pseudo code be achieved, and will I increase performance by doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're actually doing there is using JDBC to execute your SQL (even though you're obtaining the JDBC Connection from Hibernate's session). With JDBC you can do something like:

```java
public void store(int[] params1, int[] params2) {
   Connection con = session.connection();
   boolean initialAutocommitSetting = connection con.getAutoCommit();
   //disable autocommit
   con.setAutoCommit(false);
   //you only need one statement object:
   CallableStatement stmt = con.prepareCall("{ call changesalary(?,?) }");

   for (int i = 0; i < params1.length; i++) {       
       stmt.setInt(1, params1[i]);
       stmt.setInt(2, params2[i]);  
       //for each call, add the set of parameters as needed and call addBatch();
       stmt.addBatch();
    }
    //when you're done, execute your (batch) statement and see how many updates you got
    int [] updatesCount=stmt.executeBatch(); 

    //manually commit
    con.commit();

    if(updatesCount!=i) {
        //some updates didn't work
    }

    //return connection to initial autocommit setting:
    connection.setAutoCommit(initialAutocommitSetting );
}
```

Hope this helps. Javadocs: [CallableStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html), [Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to resort to pure JDBC, you have `query.setFirstResult()` to set offset of pagination, and `query.setMaxResult()` to specify page size. This requires a little bit of effort of calculation on your side: depending on the value of `query.getMaxResults()`, you decide the page size, and calculate page number. The benefit of it is you can be flexible. (only paging when is gt than 1000 records, for example)

`PageImpl` class could be useful.